# can't select a h6 tag through it's wrapping parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the `background-color` of a `h6` tag through it's wrapping parent and it works nicely:

```css
div h6 {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div> sample text
  <h6>this is h6</h6>
</div>
```

But when I change it to this code and swap the `div` with `p` it no longer applies:

```css
p h6 {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<p> sample text
  <h6>this is h6</h6>
</p>
```

is there a list of working tags with this structure?

Comment: why should it not work? It works fine for me. Are you sure that your browser didn't cache the CSS?

Comment: As @tacoshy says, your code works perfectly OK. Try making it into a SO runnable snippet and you’ll see it’s ok so something else in your code isn’t working. Use you browsers dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what is setting what.

Comment: @AHaworth true it doidnt work for me in the SO-snippet but in the IDE. Properly because of the invalid markup as a h6 as a header can not be a child element of a paragraph

Comment: @tacoshy many thanks for spotting this - my carelessness not trying it in snippet first. Apologies. My previous comment was rubbish.

Comment: `<h6>` is a valid child of `<div>`, but not a valid child of `<p>`. See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p).

Comment: thanks but now I need a list of tags that can/can not nested in each other!